# CSS: How can I make the pop over menu clickable?

Tags: html, css

I created a pop up menu here: https://jsfiddle.net/qpbmyhor/

Now I want the pop out menu links to be clickable. Right now when you hover your mouse to it, it will just dissapper and its not clickable. Also how can make the whole canvas/menus RESPONSIVE?

Here's my CSS:

```
ul.icon-menu {margin-top:29px;}
li.icon-box {width: 120px; height: 120px; list-style: none; left: -47px; position: relative; margin-bottom: 3px;}
li.icon-box.home {background: #e74c3c;}
li.icon-box.aboutme {background: #1dd0ad;}
li.icon-box.portfolio {background: #3498db;}
li.icon-box.blog {background: #f1c40f;}
li.icon-box.contact {background: #f39c12;}
.icon-box h2{Museo500-Regular; font-size: 20px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);}

.icon-box a {display: block;}



/*= TITLE BOXES
--------------------------------------------------------*/
.icon-box.home h2 { 
     z-index: -999;
     position: absolute; 
     top: 0; 
     left: 0; 
     opacity: 0; 
     background: #E74C3C; 
     line-height: 120px; 
     width: 120px; 
     -webkit-transition: all  .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
        border-left: 3px solid #a7382d;

}

.icon-box.home a:hover h2 { 
    opacity: 1; left: 120px; margin: 0;
    text-align: center;

}

.icon-box.aboutme h2 { 
     z-index: -999;
     position: absolute; 
     top: 0; 
     left: 0; 
     opacity: 0; 
     background: #1dd0ad; 
     line-height: 120px; 
     width: 120px; 
     -webkit-transition: all  .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    border-left: 3px solid #0d866e;
}

.icon-box.aboutme a:hover h2 { 
    opacity: 1; left: 120px; margin: 0;
    text-align: center;

}


.icon-box.portfolio h2 { 
     z-index: -999;
     position: absolute; 
     top: 0; 
     left: 0; 
     opacity: 0; 
     background: #3498db; 
     line-height: 120px; 
     width: 120px; 
     -webkit-transition: all  .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    border-left: 3px solid #2177b1;
}

.icon-box.portfolio a:hover h2 { 
    opacity: 1; left: 120px; margin: 0;
    text-align: center;

}


.icon-box.blog h2 { 
     z-index: -999;
     position: absolute; 
     top: 0; 
     left: 0; 
     opacity: 0; 
     background: #f1c40f; 
     line-height: 120px; 
     width: 120px; 
     -webkit-transition: all  .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    border-left: 3px solid #b8960e;
}

.icon-box.blog a:hover h2 { 
    opacity: 1; left: 120px; margin: 0;
    text-align: center;

}

.icon-box.contact h2 { 
     z-index: -999;
     position: absolute; 
     top: 0; 
     left: 0; 
     opacity: 0; 
     background: #f39c12; 
     line-height: 120px; 
     width: 120px; 
     -webkit-transition: all  .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    border-left: 3px solid #bc780d;
}

.icon-box.contact a:hover h2 { 
    opacity: 1; left: 120px; margin: 0;
    text-align: center;

}



/*= MENU ICONS
--------------------------------------------------------*/


span.icon { display: inline-block; background: url('../img/icon-sprites.png')no-repeat;  width: 32px; height: 32px; margin: 43px 40px;}
span.icon.home { background-position: 0px 0px;}
span.icon.aboutme { background-position: -36px 0px;}
span.icon.portfolio { background-position: -72px 0px;}
span.icon.blog { background-position: -109px 0px;}
span.icon.contact { background-position: -145px 0px;}
```

Any idea? if you could show me the JSFIDDLE SOLUTIONS too!

NOTE it must pop out at the bottom of the icon box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change `z-index` to `0` for `icon-box` class to achieve what you are looking for.

**For instance,**

```
.icon-box.aboutme h2, .icon-box.home h2, .icon-box.portfolio h2, .icon-box.blog h2, .icon-box.contact h2{
        z-index:0;
    }
```

**[Live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qpbmyhor/2/)**

If you want to achieve this keeping the object at the top, solution as below.

**Code:**

```
.icon-box a {
    padding: 120px;
}
```

**[Live demo - 2](https://jsfiddle.net/qpbmyhor/3/)**

Hope this helps.

Comment: its popping out on the top of the icon. It must pop out on the bottom but still clickable.

Comment: Atlest the text link must pop out below the icon menu. is that possible?

Comment: Almost there. but it must be popping out on the BOTTOM of the icon NOT on the TOP..

Comment: @KimberlyWright - here you go - https://jsfiddle.net/qpbmyhor/3/ - Hope this helps.

Comment: Just last question. How can make it responsive? How can make each boxes respoinsive on smaller devices. Just this thing and everything is good.

Comment: @KimberlyWright - Change width as per the screen width of the responsive device using media query. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you show me the JSFiddle for it man? just that last thing and I'll just mark this ok DONE. please.

Comment: Not possible, as this is extensive coding. I have shown you the way, you can now follow to reach the answer on your own :) I can only help you on stackoverflow if you stuck-up than creating solution. Hope this helps.

Comment: Mark it now CHECK.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this, you no need to write css for each menu.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<style type="text/css">
ul.icon-menu {margin-top:29px;}
li.icon-box {width: 120px; height: 120px; list-style: none; left: -47px; position: relative; margin-bottom: 3px;}
li.icon-box.home {background: #e74c3c;}
li.icon-box.aboutme {background: #1dd0ad;}
li.icon-box.portfolio {background: #3498db;}
li.icon-box.blog {background: #f1c40f;}
li.icon-box.contact {background: #f39c12;}
.icon-box h2{Museo500-Regular; font-size: 20px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);}

.icon-box a {display: block;}



/*= TITLE BOXES
--------------------------------------------------------*/
.icon-box h2 { 
     
     position: absolute; 
     top: 0; 
     left: 0; 
     opacity: 0; 
     background: #E74C3C; 
     line-height: 120px; 
     width: 120px; 
     -webkit-transition: all  .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
        border-left: 3px solid #a7382d;

}
.icon-box a:hover h2 { 
 
    opacity: 1; left: 120px; margin: 0;
    text-align: center;

}

/*= MENU ICONS
--------------------------------------------------------*/


span.icon { display: inline-block; background: url('../img/icon-sprites.png')no-repeat;  width: 32px; height: 32px; margin: 43px 40px;}
span.icon.home { background-position: 0px 0px;}
span.icon.aboutme { background-position: -36px 0px;}
span.icon.portfolio { background-position: -72px 0px;}
span.icon.blog { background-position: -109px 0px;}
span.icon.contact { background-position: -145px 0px;}


</style>
</head>

<body>

     <div class="container">
 
    <ul class="icon-menu">
    <li class="icon-box home"> 
        <a href="#">
          <span class="icon home"></span>
          <h2>Home</h2>
        </a>
    </li> 
    
    
    <li class="icon-box aboutme"> 
        <a href="#">
          <span class="icon aboutme"></span>
          <h2>About Me</h2>
        </a>
    </li>
    
    
    <li class="icon-box portfolio"> 
         <a href="#">
            <span class="icon portfolio"></span>
             <h2>Portfolio</h2>
         </a>
    </li>
    
    
       <li class="icon-box blog"> 
            <a href="#">
             <span class="icon blog"></span>
              <h2>Blog</h2>
         </a>
    </li>
    
    
       <li class="icon-box contact"> 
            <a href="#">
            <span class="icon contact"></span>
      <h2>Contact</h2>
           </a>
    </li>
    
    
       
    </ul>
    
  
    
 </div>
 

 
 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: its popping out on the BOTTOM of the icon. It must pop out on the bottom but still clickable.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please have a look on the link. 
I just noticed that you are controlling the popover element with every li  a:hover and you should avoid it.
I tried to optimize your code and I think it's better to control hover on li element instead of a tag. (It might be possible that you have some different requirement that's why you are controlling it on a:hover)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ashubuddy/qpbmyhor/4/